Dependency issue building Docker image for AWS ECR and Lambda
I am trying to run a Python function on AWS Lambda. It requires ECPy and safe-pysha3 as dependencies. When uploaded directly to Lambda I cannot get Lambda to find the pysha3 module not matter how I try and structure it. This is because pysha3 utilizes gcc to function. I have also tried uploading the dependencies inside a layer with no luck.
My approach has changed to building a Docker image of the function. This somewhat works when the Docker file uses the Python base image. Then I can get the Docker image to build completely without errors. The only problem with this is Lambda does not find the event handler for the function if you don't use an AWS base image. When I remove the event handler the code executes perfectly on Lambda but the function fails on completion of the code due to it expecting a return from the non existent event handler.
In order to run the Lambda function cleanly without a fail on completion of the code. I would need to build the Docker image using an AWS base image so that the event handler can execute the code and give a return. Unfortunately the Docker image made using the AWS base image will not build because of the safe-pysha3 dependency and it's gcc requirements. I have tried numerous ways to install gcc first from the Dockerfile during the build to no avail.
The Dockerfile variants...

The preferred complete Dockerfile that will work as required on AWS Lambda but will not build.

The error on building the preferred Dockerfile.

Any other ideas anyone might have are appreciated.

The solution is to use the following code in the Dockerfile...
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Define custom function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM python:3.12 as build-image

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# Copy function code
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the function's dependencies
RUN pip install \
--target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
    awslambdaric \
    safe-pysha3 \
    ecpy

# Use a slim version of the base Python image to reduce the final image size
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Set runtime interface client as default command for the container runtime
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
# Pass the name of the function handler as an argument to the runtime
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]


From your docker build logs I see:
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory

I believe you should be able to fix this by installing gcc as one of the steps in the Dockerfile, i.e. by adding this after your FROM statement:
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  gcc

I am basing that on https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-python-runtime-interface-client - although it might depend on which linux version you're getting from the base container. i.e. you may want to use yum instead (I think this is correct for Amazon Linux 2023), more like:
RUN yum update -y && \
  yum install -y gcc gcc-c++

